# Odoo 8 domain filter on Many2one field

Tags: python, python-2.7, odoo-8, odoo, many-to-one

I would like to make a filter on a Many2one field in Odoo 8. 
This is for the stock module.

I have created extra fields where the user can enter additional information. Now we want to filter the available fields that appear in the dropdown, or when clicking the "more" butten to show only the additional fields for that product.

This is the code for the stock.production.lot model
When product_id is updated, then the domain filter should be changed.

```
class StockProductionLot(models.Model):
    _inherit = "stock.production.lot"
    lot_lot_additional_fields = fields.One2many("lot.lot.additional.fields", "stock_production_lot")

    @api.onchange("product_id")
    def onchange_product_id(self):
        res = {}
        cat_fields = self.product_id.categ_id.lot_fields_category.lot_additional_fields
        ids = []
        for item in cat_fields:
            ids.append(item.id)
        if self.product_id:
            res["domain"] = {"lot_additional_fields": [("id", "in", "ids")]}
        return res
```

This is the model to connect the additional fields model to the lot number model. 
lot_additional_fields should be updated here.

```
class LotLotAdditionalFields(models.Model):
    _name = "lot.lot.additional.fields"
    value = fields.Char("Value")
    stock_production_lot = fields.Many2one("stock.production.lot", string="Lot/Serial Number")
    lot_additional_fields = fields.Many2one("lot.additional.fields", string="Additional field")
```

If someone could help me to solve this I would be very greatful.

======================= EDIT =============================

I have added the code to stock.production.lot

```
class StockProductionLot(models.Model):
    _inherit = "stock.production.lot"
    lot_lot_additional_fields = fields.One2many("lot.lot.additional.fields", "stock_production_lot")
    lot_additional_fields = fields.Many2one("lot.additional.fields", string="Lot additional fields")
    remarks = fields.Html("General remarks")

    @api.onchange('product_id')
    def onchange_product_id(self):
        res = {}
        if self.product_id:
            ids = self.product_id.categ_id.lot_fields_category.lot_additional_fields.mapped('id')
            res['domain'] = {'lot_lot_additional_fields': [('lot_additional_fields', 'in', ids)]}
        return res
```

to lot.additional.fields I have added product_id:

```
class LotAdditionalFields(models.Model):
    _name = "lot.additional.fields"
    name = fields.Char("Name", required=True)
    type = fields.Selection(
        [("int", "Numerical"), ("string", "Alfanumerical"), ("boolean", "Checkbox"), ("date", "Date")], required=True)
    mandatory = fields.Boolean("Mandatory field")
    display_order = fields.Integer("Display Order")
    lot_field_category = fields.Many2many("lot.field.category", string="Field Category", required=True)
    lot_lot_additional_fields = fields.One2many("lot.lot.additional.fields", "lot_additional_fields")
    product_id = fields.Many2one("product.product", string="Product ID")
```

lot_lot_additional_fields I have left the same:

```
class LotLotAdditionalFields(models.Model):
    _name = "lot.lot.additional.fields"
    value = fields.Char("Value")
    stock_production_lot = fields.Many2one("stock.production.lot", string="Lot/Serial Number")
    lot_additional_fields = fields.Many2one("lot.additional.fields", string="Additional field")
```

I will also add the xml code:

```
 <record id="view_production_lot_form" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">Stock Production Lot Form</field>
            <field name="model">stock.production.lot</field>
            <field name="inherit_id" ref="stock.view_production_lot_form"/>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <page string="Products" position="after">
                    <page string="Additional Fields">
                        <field name="lot_lot_additional_fields" >
                            <tree editable="bottom">
                                <field name="lot_additional_fields"  />
                                <field name="value"/>
                            </tree>
                        </field>
                        <h3>General remarks</h3>
                        <field name="remarks"/>
                    </page>
                </page>
            </field>
    </record>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to take into account that in the line `res["domain"] = {"lot_additional_fields": [("id", "in", "ids")]}` you are altering the domain of the model `stock.production.lot`, which by the way, seems that doesn't have any field named `lot_additional_fields` (it has a field named `lot_lot_additional_fields` instead).

```
@api.onchange('product_id')
def onchange_product_id(self):
    res = {}
    if self.product_id:
        ids = self.product_id.categ_id.lot_fields_category.lot_additional_fields.mapped('id')
        res['domain'] = {'lot_lot_additional_fields': [('lot_additional_fields', 'in', ids)]}
    return res
```

I was reading your code and now I'm sure that the code I wrote here is the right code you wanted to get in your attempt. However, I don't have any information about the views and the class `lot.additional.fields`, only about `stock.production.lot` and `lot.lot.additional.fields`, and I guess (if I understood well what you want) that this is not going to work (modification of domain in a view is not going to modify the domain of other different view) unless you have a `Many2one` field pointing to `product_id` in the `lot.additional.fields` class (which I can't see here).

**EDIT**

Ok, first correct me if I'm wrong: in your `stock_production_lot` form view, you see the tree of the field `lot_lot_additional_fields`. Here, if you open the dropdown of the field `lot_additional_fields`, you only want to be able to select those `lot_additional_fields` which belong to the same `lot_fields_category` of the `categ_id` of the `product_id` of the current `stock_production_lot`, don't you?

In this case, try this code:

**Python (put this onchange inside of your `lot.lot.additional.fields` class)**

```
@api.onchange('stock_production_lot')
def onchange_stock_production_lot(self):
    res = {}
    if stock_production_lot:
        ids = self.stock_production_lot.product_id.categ_id.lot_fields_category.lot_additional_fields.mapped('id')
        res['domain'] = {
            'lot_additional_fields': [('id', 'in', ids)]}
        }
    return res
```

**XML (modify your `view_production_lot_form` code and write this one)**

```
<record id="view_production_lot_form" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">Stock Production Lot Form</field>
    <field name="model">stock.production.lot</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="stock.view_production_lot_form"/>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <page string="Products" position="after">
            <page string="Additional Fields">
                <field name="lot_lot_additional_fields" widget="one2many_list" context="{'default_stock_production_lot': active_id}">
                    <tree editable="bottom">
                        <field name="stock_production_lot" invisible="1"/>
                        <field name="lot_additional_fields"/>
                        <field name="value"/>
                    </tree>
                </field>
                <h3>General remarks</h3>
                <field name="remarks"/>
            </page>
        </page>
    </field>
</record>
```

Comment: Hi Torvas, I have tried your solution but it does not seem to work. reason for this is that I can only put a field name in the decorator.

Comment: Ok, I've read better your question, I'm going to edit the answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your efforts, forvas. But it seems it is not ready yet. I have added some additional code. I am still fairly new to programming in Odoo so there are a lot of things to learn.

Comment: This works like a charm forvas. I can only give you one but else I would give you 10+. Just from this issue I was able to learn so much. Thank's a lot. Could you just explain to me where you got "default_stock_production_lot" and "active_id".

Comment: I'm very glad I was able to help you @Johan. I had learned both `default_` and `active_id` searching in the code (I was trying to emulate the behaviour of modules I hadn't made, and I found those). As you may know, Odoo 8 documentation is very poor, and OpenERP 7 and 6.1 ones were even worse.